# Node.js - search a file in current working directory, if file not found, traverse up the path up until the first one is found

Tags: node.js, file, search

Example:

User is searching for menu file and currently in `C:\Root\Food\Lunch\Pizza`.
The menu file is `Food` folder. 
How to traverse up the path to look for it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it with the basic functions of `fs` and `path` modules.

- https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html
- https://nodejs.org/api/path.html

The easiest way would be to use `path.sep` to split the current path and remove the last part every time you try a new directory. Or you can remove the parts using a regex, or you can add `/..` and use `path.normalize()` to see the parent dir. There are a lot of ways to do it. Then you can either stat or read the file if you need on every step and stop whenever you see that it exists.